# How to disable tab animations in @material-tailwind/react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I can't figure out how to completely remove the tab switching animation.
Any suggestions?
all the information I found in the documentation says how to change the animation, but not how to completely remove it

I tried something like that:

```
animate={{
   initial: { y: 0, x: 0 },
   mount: { y: 0, x: 0 },
   unmount: { y: 0, x: 0 },
}}
```

but it did not help

Answer (score 1):

### Background

Okay, so I've just spent way too long trying to figure this out:

The animation for the `indicator` is done via the [`framer-motion`](https://www.framer.com/motion/) library[^1](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-tailwind/blob/c636ebde65742e3fbf03adab756ad14c7e4c984e/packages/material-tailwind-react/src/components/Tabs/Tab.tsx#L84-L89), which in this case means that the animation is done by setting the `translate` property continuously throughout the animation's lifetime.

The only way I've been able to consistently overwrite the animation is by setting the `indicator`'s `className` to include the `!translate-x-0` Tailwind class to overwrite any other attempts to set the `translate` property to anything else.

### Examples Solutions

#### The `indicatorProps` Approach

```js
<TabsHeader indicatorProps={{ id: "tabs-header-indicator" }}>
    // ...

    <Tab className="[&_#tabs-header-indicator]:!translate-x-0">
    </Tab>

    // ...
</TabsHeader>
```

#### The Theme Approach

```js
// index.jsx

import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-tailwind/react";

const theme = {
    tab: {
        styles: {
            base: {
                indicator: {
                    translate: "!translate-x-0"
                },
            },
        },
    }
};

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);

reactRoot.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ThemeProvider value={theme}>
            // ...
        </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Warning: hacky approach

The only way I found to bypass animation is force re-rendering via React `key` attribute. This is not ideal, but does prevent the animation from happening. Thought to share this, but hopefully someone could point out a better way!

```
<Tabs key={Math.random()}>
   {/* ... */}
</Tabs>
```